# Edit very large sql dump/text file (on linux)

Tags: linux, mysql, large-files

I have to import a large mysql dump (up to 10G).  However the sql dump already predefined with a database structure with index definition.  I want to speed up the db insert by removing the index and table definition.

That means I have to **remove/edit** the first few lines of a **10G** text file.  What is the most efficient way to do this **on linux**?

Programs that require loading the entire file into RAM will be an overkill to me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Rather than *removing* the first few lines, try editing them to be whitespace.

The `hexedit` program can do this-- it reads files in chunks, so opening a 10GB file is no different from opening a 100KB file to it.

```
$ hexedit largefile.sql.dump
tab (switch to ASCII side)
space (repeat as needed until your header is gone)
F2 (save)/Ctrl-X (save and exit)/Ctrl-C (exit without saving)
```

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly!  Also your detail solution helped me a lot! thanks!

Comment: For those without access to any repository, you can get the source for hexedit from: http://rigaux.org/hexedit.html

Comment: hexedit, sed or custom script: http://muras.eu/2017/03/05/editing-big-mysqldump-files

Answer (score 7):

[joe](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/) is an editor that works well with large files. I just used it to edit a ~5G SQL dump file. It took about a minute to open the file and a few minutes to save it, with very little use of swap (on a system with 4G RAM).

Comment: I used it for a 130GB file and Joe worked quite well as well with a small memory footprint

Comment: I just used it for a 30gb file...took like 5min to load on 16gb memory machine with 8GB swap...

Comment: ```sudo apt install joe```

Comment: Edited 100GB dump.sql. It took some time, but it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/OLD_TEXT/NEW_TEXT/g' < oldfile > newfile
```

or

```
cat file | sed 's/OLD_TEXT/NEW_TEXT/g' > newfile
```

Answer (score -1):

Perl can read the file line by line:

perl -pi.bak -e 's/^create index/--create index/'

Comment: This will require another 10GB of free space, and whatever time it takes to stream the whole dump from one file to a new file.